# Restrictions for Fortran loops associated with the worksharing or simd loop constructs

Tags: fortran, openmp

OpenMP for Fortran has a few loop-related constructs like the work-sharing do loop construct, simd loop construct etc. These constructs can have one or more Fortran loops related to them. The latter is when there are collapse or ordered clauses. I am looking for the restrictions placed on these Fortran loops by the OpenMP constructs. Particularly whether these loops can be without control, DO WHILE or DO Concurrent.

The OpenMP 4.5 standard specifically states the following in Section 2.7.1. However, I could not find similar statements in the latest versions of the standard like OpenMP 5.2. Has this been reworded or removed from the standard?
"19 • The do-loop cannot be a DO WHILE or a DO loop without loop control."

The OpenMP 5.2 standard includes restrictions for DO CONCURRENT constructs. There are restrictions that prevent OpenMP directives from appearing in a WHERE, FORALL or DO CONCURRENT construct. But I could not find a restriction for DO CONCURRENT appearing as the associated loop of a work-sharing do loop construct or simd loop construct.

Could a clarification on these be provided or a pointer provided to the relevant section in the standard? Thanks in advance.

I have browsed through the standard but could not find relevant sections. It is possible I have missed it, if so apologies in advance.

Comment: A `do while` and a `do` without loop control inherently have dependencies between iterations and imply an unknown iteration count; a `do concurrent` explicitly ensures no dependency between iterations and a known iteration count. As these have very different implications for parallelization it would be good for us to see more on what you understand about these aspects and/or focus on what clarification you require.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree that DO WHILE and DO without loop-control have unknown iteration counts and are in general not suitable to be associated with OpenMP loop constructs. DO-CONCURRENT has different semantics and can itself have multiple loops associated with it. Besides it can also have masks. This makes it difficult to have a DO-CONCURRENT loop that is associated with an OpenMP loop construct. I would like the standard to be more vocal and say something similar to OpenMP 4.5 standard.
"The do-loop cannot be a DO WHILE, DO loop without loop-control, or a DO CONCURRENT loop".

Comment: The mask expression of a do concurrent is evaluated exactly once, before any iteration commences. The number of iterations, and exactly which iterations, performed is known before the loop is executed. A loop which is like "do these N independent iterations where the indexes {i,j,k} are from the set S" is wholly unlike a `do while` and `do` without loop control that I'm afraid I don't see why they should all be subject to the same restrictions

Comment: That said, a `do concurrent` is not a canonical loop.